# How to draw on a canvas from an async task?

Tags: android, canvas

I have a class called RectLine which extends from `AsyncTask`. 
In the `MainActivity` class, in the method `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` a `RectLine` (`l1`) object is created. I also pass a reference of the `Canvas` and Paint objects needed to draw.  However  I can't see anything on the screen when I call the `l1.execute()` method. 
I only can see the log messeges I print on the `doInBackground` method, for this reason I'm sure the code is executing well. 
But nothing is printed on the device screen.

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));


        //new LineaRecta(x1, y1, x2, y2, b)
        LineaRecta l1 = new LineaRecta(0, getHeight(), getWidth(), 0, getHeight());

        LineaRecta l1 = new LineaRecta( 0, getHeight(), getWidth(), 0, getHeight());
        l1.setAnchoCanvas(getWidth());
        l1.setCanva(canvas);
        l1.setPaint(paint);
        l1.execute();
    }

 @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    float y;        
    for(float x=0; x<anchoCanvas;x++){
        y=(m*x)+b;
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, Punto.RADIO, paint);                      
    }
    return null;
}
```

My guess is, I can't draw on a canvas directly from a background thread.

is this correct ?
What is a better way to do this ?

Comment: That's the point of main UI thread. Although in your async task, you can implement onPostExecute() method, then call the UI thread to draw your circle.

Comment: You can use the background thread to tell the UI thread to draw something but you can not directly draw from the background thread.

Answer (score 3):

To do something in mainUI thread from background use this wrapper:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //do something
            }
        });
```

to redraw your View use this code:

`myview.invalidate();`  <- this method calls `onDraw()` of your view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use the following line in `doInBackground(Void... voids)`:

```
 canvas.drawCircle(p.getX(), p.getY(), Punto.RADIO, paint);
```

What you can do in order to achieve your goal is to call the UI thread while background computation is still running by calling publishProgress() the following method inside the doInBackground method.

Comment: And do the drawing in `onProgressUpdate()`, which OP will need to override in the AsyncTask subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to redraw your View use this code:

myview.invalidate(); <- this method calls onDraw() of your view.

paoladelloglio.54